# Maximize button inconsistency

Tags: gnome, 20.04, window-buttons

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

I just realised that some windows have no maximise button,

in this picture

[image: in this picture]

for example Darktable and Rapid Photo Downloader haven't the maximize button, while libreoffice and Files window do.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Some extra info:

```
domenico@domenico-HP-ENVY-Notebook:~$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.36.2
domenico@domenico-HP-ENVY-Notebook:~$ loginctl show-session 2 -p Type
Type=x11
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with display resolution and darktable (don't know for rapid photo downloader):
https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/issues/5273